# Persistent assignment in data.table with .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I'm **struggling** with .SD calls in data.table.

In particular, I'm trying to identify some logical characteristic within a grouping of data, and draw some identifying mark in another variable. Canonical application of .SD, right?

From FAQ 4.5, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf, imagine the following table:

```
library(data.table) # 1.9.5

DT = data.table(a=rep(1:3,1:3),b=1:6,c=7:12)
DT[,{ mySD = copy(.SD)
      mySD[1, b := 99L]
      mySD },
    by = a]
##   a  b  c
## 1: 1 99  7
## 2: 2 99  8
## 3: 2  3  9
## 4: 3 99 10
## 5: 3  5 11
## 6: 3  6 12
```

I've assigned these values to b (using the ':=' operator) and so when I re-call DT, I expect the same output. But, unexpectedly, I'm met with the original table:

```
DT
##    a b  c
## 1: 1 1  7
## 2: 2 2  8
## 3: 2 3  9
## 4: 3 4 10
## 5: 3 5 11
## 6: 3 6 12
```

Expected output was the original frame, with persistent modifications in 'b':

```
DT
##   a  b  c
## 1: 1 99  7
## 2: 2 99  8
## 3: 2  3  9
## 4: 3 99 10
## 5: 3  5 11
## 6: 3  6 12
```

Sure, I can copy this table into another one, but that doesn't seem consistent with the ethos.

```
DT2 <- copy(DT[,{ mySD = copy(.SD)
                  mySD[1, b := 99L]
                  mySD },
               by = a])
DT2
##   a  b  c
## 1: 1 99  7
## 2: 2 99  8
## 3: 2  3  9
## 4: 3 99 10
## 5: 3  5 11
## 6: 3  6 12
```

It feels like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: I'd recommend going thro' the *Reference Semantics* vignette [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) if you've not already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mentioned FAQ is just showing a workaround on how to modify (a temprory copy of) `.SD` but it *won't* update your original data *in place*. A possible solution for you problem would be something like

```
DT[DT[, .I[1L], by = a]$V1, b := 99L]
DT
#    a  b  c
# 1: 1 99  7
# 2: 2 99  8
# 3: 2  3  9
# 4: 3 99 10
# 5: 3  5 11
# 6: 3  6 12
```